# How to keep information about multiple changes related to a model

Tags: python, django

Will try to make a general example:
I have a "Material" model with a Foreign key to a "Price".
During the year 2020, a "Material" has one price, but in the year 2021 I want to change the "Price" but still keep track of the history of price changes.

The summed cost of a "Material" consumption during 2020 should not change because of a "Price" change during 2021.

Is there a common strategy to handle this in Python/Django?

Comment: Have your "Consumption" (or whatever you name it) model also have a foreign key to `Price`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat no it has not. Is that the common strategy - using a model for every potential -aggregation- of other models?

Comment: You want to track `Consumption` right? Doesn't that mean that it should be an entity in your database schema? Anyway although I have never used Clojure / Datomic I am sure that under the hoods it simply makes copies with the extra data for the year. So this Foreign Key strategy I suggest is likely very similar to what was done there. Anyway you describe your problem in a very abstract manner perhaps if you had put your models in the question it would have been more clear what you mean.

Comment: I will try to expand the question with a more concrete example.
Datomic keeps copies of every change. So you will always know what the facts where in a given time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the Price as a model which is something as follows

```
class Prices(models.Model):
     material = models.ForeignKey(Material,...)
     year = models.IntegerField()
     prices = models.DoubleField()
```

Then you can get the price of a material in a certain year.

Comment: Sure. That is a solution.  In this case and example, price seems sane to keep creating for every material.